# Как лучше подключать заголовки во внешних классах? (Qt, C++)

Tags: c++, qt

Например, я разрабатываю несколько кастомных виджетов, для каждого создаю отдельный .h и .cpp файл. В этих файлах(классах) мне нужны заголовки `#include <QtWidgets>` или `#include <QLabel>`. Но если я подключу их внутри своего .h файла, а потом подключу свой класс и `<QtWidgets>` еще и в `main.cpp`, то получается я два раза подключаю один файл, а это же не очень хорошо. Если я не буду подключать ничего в своих классах, то если забуду подключить какой-либо заголовок в `main.cpp`, то ничего не будет работать.
 Где и как их правильно подключить? Как это обычно делают?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Для этого есть [#pragma once](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pragma_once):

```
// header.h
#pragma once
...
```

и [include gruards](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard):

```
// header.h
#ifndef __HEADER_H__
#define __HEADER_H__

...

#endif // __HEADER_H__
```

которые не дадут заинклудиться хэдеру дважды и вызвать ошибку компиляции. А повторять директивы `#include` иногда лучше для:

1. наглядности
2. модульности

ведь если вы уберете кастомный виджет с кучей полезных хэдеров из `main.cpp`, то компилятор посыплется руганью о том, что вообще не связано с тем виджетом. Представляете себе такой веселый рефакторинг?

Comment: Ещё стоит добавить небольшое правило: в файле должны быть только те заголовочные файлы, элементы которых используются в этом файле. Другими словами, если в `.h` кастомного виджета нужен `QWidget`, а для вывода *логов* этого кастомного класса нужен, скажем, `qDebug` То включение `QtGlobal` дожно быть в `.cpp` файле, `QWidget` - в `.h` файле

Comment: Насчет `include guards`, будет ли он правильно работать, если кастомный виджет подключается впервые(`#include<customWidget>`), а следом подключается заголовок(`#include<QtWidgets>`), который уже содержит кастомный виджет(внутри `customWidget.h` уже подключен `<QtWidgets>`)?

Comment: @user1056837, а разве не удобнее будет подключить все нужные хедеры в .h файле?

Comment: @Nik, это ведёт к неопрятности в коде. Кроме того проще становится перемещать файлы в случае пресловутого рефакторинга. Также структура становится более прозрачной - видно, какие средства задействованы для решения конкретной прикладной задачи (реализации класса), а хедеры в иерархии классов также становится чище.

Comment: @user1056837, ну а на производительность это как-то влияет? Просто на мой вкус, удобно, когда все хедеры подключены в одном месте и видно, что используется для решения конкретной задачи.

Comment: @Nik Да. Представьте работу препроцессора: он натыкается на ifndef впервые, дефайн (__HEADER_H__) не объявлен => входим (натыкаемся на объявление __HEADER_H__), инклудим заголовочник. Теперь натыкаемся снова на ifndef (второе включение), только __HEADER_H__ уже объявлен => выходим из файла.

Comment: @Nik Вам, в идеале, не стоит знать о том, что используется (инклудится) внутри хэдеров. Представьте, что это черный ящик. Ущерба для компиляции практически нет (для рантайма - тем более), а тонну времени вы сэкономите в случае рефакторинга, как я писал в ответе.

Comment: @free_ze, я вот и представил работу препроцессора. Натыкаемся на обьявление **HEADER_H**, инклюдим заголовочник и `<QtWidgets>`, потом натыкаемся (в `main.cpp`) на инклюд `<QtWidgets>`, там условий никаких нет и инклюдим `<QtWidgets>` второй раз...

Comment: @Nik условие включения находится внутри самого `<QtWidgets>`, а не снаружи. Поэтому не важно, где Вы его подключаете. Второй, третий и т.д. разы тело включаемого файла не будет реально включено, потому что это приведет к ошибке компиляции в противном случае.

Comment: @Nik Вас это не должно волновать как раз потому) Разработчики QtWidgets это [тоже предусмотрели](http://cep.xray.aps.anl.gov/software/qt4-x11-4.2.2-browser/dd/d07/src_2gui_2kernel_2qwidget_8h-source.html)

Comment: @free_ze, ах вот оно что, ну тогда всё понятно, спасибо.

Answer (score 5):

Подключать заголовочные файлы надо там, где они действительно нужны. Довольно часто бывает достаточно (например, если используются только указатели или ссылки на тип) в своем заголовочном файле поместить только предварительную декларацию используемого типа через:

```
class Sometype;
```

А `#include "Sometype.h"` сделать уже в файле реализации `*.cpp`, там, где действительно нужно знать всё о типе `Sometype`. Такой подход может существенно сэкономить время при сборке проекта.

Comment: То есть например в `customLabel.h` я пишу просто `class QLabel;`, а в `customLabel.cpp` я уже подключаю `#include <QLabel>`, я правильно понял? А в чем польза такой записи?

Comment: @Nik, поняли правильно. О пользе можете почитать [Майерса](http://cpp.com.ru/meyers_1/ch5.html#t45).

Comment: Сейчас попробовал использовать предварительную декларацию - обьявил в .h файле `class QWidget`, а в .cpp сделал инклюд, но компилятор выкидывает ошибки в стиле "базовый класс не определен", то есть будто класс не определен.

Comment: @Nik надо смотреть как используется `QWidget` в .h файле.

Comment: От него наследуется мой класс. Больше в .h файле он никак не упоминается.

Comment: @Nik для наследования нужно знать размер, то есть нужно полное определение класса.

Answer (score 4):

Большинство заголовочных файлов включают `define` и условия `ifndef` для того, чтобы избежать таких ситуаций. *QtCreator* автоматически создает эти макросы, если Вы создали их из него.
Не стоит беспокоиться по этому поводу, если эти макросы у вас прописаны.
Как мне известно, в стандартных файлах *Qt* всё это уже есть.